# No sound on TV via HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I can't get sound to my TV which I connected via HDMI cable to my HP Pavilion g6 Laptop running under OS Ubuntu 12.04-64bit.

I checked [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001545) post which indicates a solution, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Go to your sound settings and make sure you have your HDMI audio selected. Sometimes it doesn't change from the default integrated sound settings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...my sound settings only show one entry.../home/jg/Desktop/SoundSettings.png

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...my sound settings only show one entry...https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/109765435561724337623/albums/posts/5797395730233476786?hl=en

Comment: Here is more info: there are two Audio Devices in this Laptop and I guess I don't have the right driver for them: 00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series] Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 43 00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 169b Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16